# How to center 2 floating divs within another div

Tags: css, html, haml, centering

I have the following haml code to display a user avatar and a user nickname + bio

```
.page_section.header
  .user_info_container
    //float left
    .avatar_container.pull_left
      .avatar
        %a.fancy{href: "<%= user.original_avatar_url %>"}
          %img{:src => "/v1/users/<%= user.nickname %>/picture/large"}
    //float left
    .user_details.pull_left
      .name
        %h1 <%= user.name %>
        <%= user.description %>

    .clearfix
```

I would like to center my .user_info_container in the center of the .page_section.header div. How can I achieve that. I have the following css

```
.page_section.header {
  padding: 0 0 6px;
  min-height: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  .user_info_container {
    .avatar_container {
      width: 12%
    }

    .user_details {
      width: 88%
    }

  }
}
```

[image]

Effect I want to achieve... to center the avatar and text in the middle of the the parent div (.page_section)

Comment: Please post HTML, not everybody knows HAML.

Comment: Same goes for CSS/SASS (just noticed that that isn't CSS) :)

Comment: can you show us you browser render code or create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Are people seriously voting down the question because it contains HAML/SASS?

Answer (score 16):

You can achive same effect with `display:inline-block;` to child  and `text-align:center;` to parent element

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/igufin/1)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="div1">One </div>
    <div class="div2">two</div>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.main {text-align:center;border:solid 1px #000;}
.main .div1,
.main .div2  {display:inline-block; border:solid 1px #f00; margin:2px;padding:10px}
```

Comment: But it does not seem to work if the divs are floating i.e. float left and right?

Comment: why you need to float the div? when you can use `display:inline-block;` in your condition

Answer (score 0):

You can always make your floating `divs`'s parent inline-block and center it with giving `text-align: center` to the grand-paren

**HTML**

```
<div class="text-center">
    <div class="parent"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.text-center {text-align: center;}
.parent {overflow: hidden; display: inline-block;}
.child {float: left}
```

Comment: Posting a code-only answer does little for answering the original question. Please provide some explanation as to why your answer is the correct answer.